# PowerShell ANSI Escape color not working with Format-Table

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-5.0

## Issue

For some reason the ANSI Escape colors in use with Format-Table loses the column alignment. Any suggestions to correct this behavior? The line that is causing this issue is

`"$e[${color}m$($dbValue)${e}[0m"`

Yet, if we don't use ANSI Escape the function works fine.

Expected results (colors removed)

```
id    author         title                genre    price  publish_date
--    ------         -----                -----    -----  ------------
Bk001 LName, FName   XML Powershell Guide Computer 104.95 2020-10-01
Bk002 LName2, FName2 Python Guide         Computer 104.95 2020-12-16
```

Current results (colors removed)

```
id    author         title                         genre             price  publish_date
--    ------         -----                         -----             -----  ------------
Bk001 LName, FName   XML Powershell Guide Computer 104.95 2020-10-01  
Bk002 LName2, FName2 Python Guide         Computer 104.95 2020-12-16
```

### Sample code

```
$myBooks = [xml] @"
<catalog>
   <book id="Bk001">
      <author>LName, FName</author>
      <title>XML Powershell Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>104.95</price>
      <publish_date>2020-10-01</publish_date>
   </book>
   <book id="Bk002">
      <author>LName2, FName2</author>
      <title>Python Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>104.95</price>
      <publish_date>2020-12-16</publish_date>      
   </book>
</catalog>
"@

# Colors
# Red   31
# Green 32
$ColorRed = '31'
$ColorGreen = '32'

function ColorValue {
    param (     
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)][string]$dbValue,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)][string]$color
    )
    $e = [char]27

    if ($color -eq [string]::Empty) {
        $color = $ColorGreen
    }

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($dbValue)) {
        $dbValue = 'NULL'
        $color = $ColorRed
    }
    "$e[${color}m$($dbValue)${e}[0m"
}

# title, genre, price, publish_date
$myBooks.catalog.book | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap -Property id, author, 
@{name = 'title'; expression = { (ColorValue $_.title)}}, 
@{name='genre';expression={ColorValue $_.genre $ColorRed}} , price, publish_date
```

### PowerShell info

```
> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

## Update

Even upgrading to PowerShell 5.1.19041.1 the issue remains. It is actually happening in VS Code PowerShell Terminal rather than PowerShell... Go figure. Any workaround for VS Code or file it as a bug?

Comment: [It works fine](https://imgur.com/PQAQC2Y) on the PC I'm repairing, `PSVersion 5.1.19041.1`, `BuildVersion 10.0.19041.1`, so I'll assume that the issue is with your current console/settings.

Comment: I am also seeing the same issue in 5.1.19041.1. Found the issue, it is not PowerShell but rather VS Code PowerShell output is different then what PowerShell is displaying.

Comment: Dont use the VSCode terminal then, you wouldn't drive a replica if you had the genuine car in the same garage! Anyhow, as your issue is not related to your code, and a configuration issue with VSCode, you should really delete your question and post it to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask), which deals with software issues.

Comment: Well VS Code is where I am developing the scripts and the output should be dependable. VS Code PowerShell  Preview is the extension that was causing the issue. I may delete this later but going to reference this for the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue isn't in the code but rather the VS Code: PowerShell extension. Filed this as a bug: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/2815